# How to use mstor?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am opening a mail store following the instructions, using the code below, and it works hard, spending a few seconds to decode my eml, but then I have no folder and no message. No exception thought. What to do?

```
        Store store = session.getStore(new URLName("mstor:test-data/01-one-time-test/215.eml"));
        store.connect();
        // read messages from Inbox..
        Folder inbox = store.getDefaultFolder();                        
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Folder [] folders = inbox.list();
        System.out.println("folder count: " + folders.length);
        Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
        System.out.println("message count: " + messages.length);
```

=====================================================
I resolved it:

you need to provide to the mstor a folder with mbox files. Then mstor works beautifully. The good part about it is that there is a maven download.

Ciao!

Answer (score 1):

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        this.properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "mstor");
        this.properties.setProperty("mstor.mbox.metadataStrategy", "none");
        this.properties.setProperty("mstor.mbox.cacheBuffers", "disabled");
        this.properties.setProperty("mstor.mbox.bufferStrategy", "mapped");
        this.properties.setProperty("mstor.metadata", "disabled");
        this.properties.setProperty("mstor.mozillaCompatibility", "enbled");
        this.session = Session.getInstance(this.properties);

    try {

        final Store store = session.getStore(new URLName("mstor:" + path));
        try {

            store.connect();
            this.inbox = (MStorFolder) store.getFolder(path);//getDefaultFolder();//.getFolder(path);
            this.inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            count =inbox.getMessageCount();
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

      }
```

Comment: Try setting the properties shown above and read from the path shown above in the code. You can read from the inbox messages.